# What is the significance of limit and why is there always a difference between the value of x and the limiting value?

Tags: calculus

Let $x$ be an independent variable and $y = f(x) = (x^2-1)/(x-1)$. If we draw the graph,then at $x = 1$, we cannot draw any point as y will be equal to $\frac00$,an indeterminate form. My book says if, without directly taking $x = 1$, $x$ is taken close to $1$, $f(x)$ also approaches a certain value, let $a$. Thus the value of $f(x)$ becomes close to $a$, when $x$ approaches $1$; limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $1 = a$.

A simple bookish explanation. My problem is that what is the necessity of this concept. We know that when $x = 1$, $f(x) = \frac00$. What is the problem with $\frac00$? If there is any problem, how can the limit concept solve this? $x$ will always be $\frac00$, no matter what $f(x)$ is when $x$ approaches $1$. $a$, the limiting value, can never be equal to $\frac00$. I am unable to make any sense with the limit. Please help.

My last question is my book says you cannot make the difference ie. magnitude of $x-a = 0$ hence you cannot make $x = a$, where $a$ is the limiting value. Why it is so? Help.

Comment: Of course $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. But in a huge number of applications, it is useful to know what $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ approaches as $x$ approaches $a$.

Comment: Yes,I know 0/0 is undefined.But,what i want to know is that why 0/0 makes problem & also how limit that deals with the x that are not 1 but close to 1 solve this problem of 0/0?

Comment: As far as I know, limits themselves don't have much use apart from understanding functions, convergence and other concepts. Limits can help you tell how a function is behaving *near* a point, but the point itself doesn't matter. However, when we study derivatives, that is a special form of limit:
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

This is another form of limit that gives the value $\frac00$ at $x=a$. However, as you will study later, this is immensely  useful. This limit, the derivative, gives you the slope of the tangent of curve, and if you solve the equation $f'(x)=0$, it lets you find min/max.

Comment: To find the limit of,let,f(x) when x tends to p,we take limit of f(p + h),where h tends to 0.After making calculations,we replace h with zero & get the limit.But h cannot be 0 as we have taken earlier that h is a number close to 0 but not equal to 0.It seems to me a contradiction.How can I get rid of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 0/0, you have the problem that you can get anything, depending on how you approach it. For example, $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}x=2 $$ while $$  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x}x=-1 $$ If we are close to x=0, the x's cancel and we get the value. However, if we set x=0 then 2*0=0 and -1*0=0 for the numerators, leaving us stumped.

In real analysis, you limits are defined much better (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit). The limit exists if, given any distance to the point that the function is approaching, you can find a value of x close enough to force the function to be that close.

Take the limit you gave as an example. If you say "Hey, I bet you can't get that limit within 1 unit of two," I can tell you to check when x=1.5 and then f[x]=2.5. If you ask for it to be within a thousandth, I can tell you to check x=1.0001. Lo and behold, it's within a thousandth.